# How do I call this method in objective-C (iOS)?

Tags: objective-c, methods, call, declare

I have spent literally hours and hours trying to find the answer to this. I have tried [what I feel anyway!] to be everything. And I cannot call this method in my code with out getting this error:

> Receiver type NSString for instance message does not declare a method with selector `returnAsDoubleDigits:`

I was trying to refactor my code so I could reuse this method to return single digit numbers (converted to `NSString`) as double digit strings (i.e. `4` becomes `04`).

Please can anyone help me here? Have I even declared it correctly etc.? Thank you so much! :)

Call something like:

```
[doubleDigitString returnAsDoubleDigits: singleDigitString];
```

Header file:

```
- (NSString *)returnAsDoubleDigits: (NSString *)digits;
```

Implementation file:

```
- (NSString *)returnAsDoubleDigits: (NSString *)digits {
    if (digits.length == 1) return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"0%@", digits];
    else return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"0%@", digits];
}
```

Comment: What class does `doubleDigitString` belong to?

Comment: @Randy I feel that while there was a good cleanup there was to much of a style change that is just personal preference in the implementation.

Comment: @CocoaFu First I thought of making the question more understandable by me, but then I decided to make the code a bit simpler and less messy. Less code = less potential bugs. But the most important reason was of course of getting my personal style. I do that everywhere, even on template code on my computer that I delete later (for experimenting). :-p

Comment: If that method is in your category class AND from another library, you should google "Category methods don't work in iOS" and you will find some interesting stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you calling it from? in the same class? Is this what you intended?

```
NSString* doubleDigitString = [self returnAsDoubleDigits:digits];
```

You could always use [categories](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) too.

```
@implementation NSString (mycategory)


-(NSString *) returnAsDoubleDigits
{
   NSString* doubleDigits = nil;
   if (self.length == 1) {
    doubleDigits = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"0%@",
                    self];
   } else {
    doubleDigits = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"0%@",
                      self];
   }
   return doubleDigits;
}
@end
```

and then use

```
 NSString* doubleDigitString = [singleDigitString returnAsDoubleDigits];
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are calling the method on an object of type `NSString`, when you've declared the method in whatever class you actually put it in.  You can solve this two ways: with a category on NSString, or by directing your message to an object of the type that your method is declared in.

Here's how to do a category:

In `NSString+doubleDigit.h`:

```
@interface NSString (doubleDigit)
    -(NSString*)doubleDigit;
@end
```

In `NSString+doubleDigit.m`

```
@implementation NSString (doubleDigit)

-(NSString*)doubleDigit {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", [self integerValue]];
}

@end
```

Then in files where you want to make this conversion, `#include "NSString+doubleDigit.h"` and simply write:

```
NSString *doubleDigitString = [singleDigitString doubleDigit];
```

Comment: Ah I think I see. Perhaps context would also help?

`NSDateComponents *timeDifference = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:itemLengthDate  toDate:hourTargetDate  options:0];`

and then I am getting `timeDifference minute` and `timeDifference second` individually at the moment. How do I return the timeDifference in format mm:ss without going through all the above bother?

[should that have been my original question I wonder...!]

Comment: OO sorry, I think I've seen the solution. Cast the output double to an int and then call the line you gave me: `NSString *startTimeSecString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02i", [timeDifference second]];` No ifs, no calls.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have here, it looks like you haven't added the method to the class which `doubleDigitString` belongs to. Check out [Objective-C Categories](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) to add to the existing implementation of a class.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this the wrong way, you are attempting to call that method on a NSString class type but that method is not declared for NSStrings.

I assume you've declared that method in your own class. If you are using it in the same class as the implementation, you can do something like:

```
NSString *doubleDigitString = [self returnAsDoubleDigits:singleDigitString];
```

'self' refers to the class of your implementation. To have it work with NSStrings like you've shown above, you'd need to use a category but I'm not going to go into that because it'll confuse things further for something simple like what you are trying to achieve.

I think you need to revise the basics of Objective C before you delve in if it's taken you hours to get something simple like this working.

Comment: dont take me saying hours too literally please :P But people learn / remember etc in different ways, and sometimes one needs to see things applicable to them to make it click.

Comment: Well you did use the word literally in your post so one assumes you meant it as not an exaggeration. Of course we all like to see examples and give different things a go till we fully understand but like I said, this is pretty fundamental stuff in Objective C

Answer (score 0):

From what you have here, it looks like you haven't added the method to the class which doubleDigitString belongs to. Check out Objective-C Categories to add to the existing implementation of a class.

Answer (score -1):

You have not declared the categories correctly.

```
NSString *singleDigitString = [doubleDigitString returnAsDoubleDigits];
NSString+DoubleDigit.h file

@interface NSString (doubleDigit)
- (NSString*) returnAsDoubleDigits;
@end

NSString+DoubleDigit.m file

@implementation NSString (doubleDigit)

- (NSString*) returnAsDoubleDigits {
    NSString* doubleDigits = nil;
    if ([self length] == 1) {
        doubleDigits = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"0%@",self];
    } else { 
        doubleDigits = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", self];
    } 
    return doubleDigits; 
}
@end
```

Comment: Maybe the poster didn't but neither have you. What is the point of instance method if it doesn't act on the instance?